# Radicals : How to remember suffix-es, readings and positions?

Tags: meaning, kanji, radicals

There are 214 radicals, and their positions can be either Hen, Tsukuri, Ashi/ Ashi Variant, Kanmuri, Nyō, Tare or Kamae/ Kamae Variant. 
One example 衝(oposition), so this kanji is made of the kanji 行(to go) and 重(weight), 行 stands for gyo-gamae(kamae position) and this is where I need help:

-) Is it true that the 行 makes the semantic part and 重 the phonetic part of the kanji 衝?

-) If yes is it always so that that the kanji which presents the radical of the main kanji makes the semantic part and the other kanji the phonetic part?

-) Some radicals have suffixes based on their position like ninnyō, wakanmuri, tsutsumigamae, etc., but what with the others with suffixes like **gashira** does it mean that they are phonetic and semantic(phono-semantic) kanjis and they can be placed **anywhere** and does that apply to the **other kanjis which don't have those suffix endings** like : ~hen, ~ben, ~ri, ~kuri, ~tsukuri, ~ashi, ~kanmuri, ~ganmuri, ~nyō, ~tare, ~dare, ~kamae, ~gamae and the ones with this suffixes are they always semantic or can they be phonetic or even phono-semantic?

Comment: Sometimes the radical of a 形声文字 can't be the semantic element, simply because the semantic element wasn't chosen as one of the 214 traditional radicals.  For example, the radical of 錦 is 金, the phonetic portion.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me to remember them easier :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that 衝 is traditionally / generally considered as [ semantic 行 + phonetic 重 ].

However it is not always the case. For example [衡]{こう} ( as in 平衡, 均衡 ), which looks pretty much like 衝 in appearance, is believed to be from semantic [ 角 + 大 ] ( said to represent "a yoked ox" ) + phonetic 行.

Similar cases can happen also with other radicals. For example, you can compare:

> 闇 / 閣 / 閲 [ semantic 門 + phonetic 音/各/兌 ] 
>   問 / 聞 / 悶 [ semantic 口/耳/心 + phonetic 門 ] 
>   開 / 閉 / 間 / 関 [ semantic + semantic ]

Comment: Thanks‼, I think I understand enough about the radicals now and if there's anything left about them I will probably learn it by studying the other kanjis. ◕‿◕

Comment: But you don't have to be too nervous, because this kind of "kanji with phonetic part pretending to be a radical" are not really abounding. OTTOMH all I came up with is 飾 (with phonetic radical 食), in addition to snailboat's 錦 and my 衡. (問/聞/悶 will actually be found in radical sections of 口/耳/心 respectively in dictionaries.) So, in most cases you can consider as "radical = semantic". Anyway, go for it and good luck!